# Why does the string replace method not work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement replace on a string in JavaScript, but no luck so far. Can anyone please help me with it?

This is my code:

```
var message = $('#Message').val();
if (message.includes('%fullname%')) {
        console.log(message);
        message.replace(/%fullname%/g, "some name");
        console.log(message);
}
```

And this is what I get in the console: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbdRM.png)

Comment: Don't forget strings are ***immutable*** (i.e. they can't be changed). `String.prototype.replace` creates a new string instance with the result being that of the current string `message` after the `.replace()` method has been executed on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're ignoring the result of [the `.replace()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).  You can overwrite your existing variable with the result:

```
message = message.replace(/%fullname%/g, "some name");
```

(This has *nothing* to do with jQuery.  `String.prototype.replace()` is standard JavaScript.)

Demo:

```js
var message = '%fullname%';
if (message.includes('%fullname%')) {
  console.log(message);
  message = message.replace(/%fullname%/g, "some name");
  console.log(message);
}
```

Comment: thanks. Although I feel stupid for asking that and not seeing such an obvious error in my method, and I don't think anybody will ever need this question, but deleting it will not be fair to you. thank you!